# bash: pinging hostnames (errormessages: value too great for bash)

Tags: bash, ping, hostname

basically im reading in some mac-addresses from an sql-datebase. Then I parse them into an ping-able hostname (adding suffix and prefix).
Then I ilterate through the array and ping those hostnames, and in the LAST value of the array I receive the error message:

```
value too great for base (error token is "64167f066aa1")
```

My code looks currently like this:

```
MAC = 'reading from sql-db'
for i in "${MAC[@]}"
do
NMAC+=($(echo -n "prefix_" && echo -n $i && echo ".suffix"));
done
ping=($(ping -c 1 ${NMAC[$i]} &> /dev/null && echo success || echo fail))
```

And in the following code I use the problematic variable ping:

```
ping -q -c1 ${NMAC[$i]} > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
echo "online"
else
echo "offline"
fi
```

Do you guys have any ideas? why is it always the last-line of the mac-address-array when all previous mac-address were successfull?

Answer (score 0):

change

```
ping=($(ping -c 1 ${NMAC[$i]} &> /dev/null && echo success || echo fail))
```

To

```
PING=($(ping -c 1 ${NMAC[$i]} &> /dev/null && echo success || echo fail))
```

ping is a command so you should not use it as variable.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work, but inded. Its confusiing that I have a variablename equaling with a command ..